# SIGSEGV crash while using delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, segmentation-fault

I keep receiving this crash report and I can't figure out where the problem is. I understand that `SIGSEGV` exception type is usually due to a memory management issue.

Crash log,

```
zException Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0x10
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x394db0fc objc_retain + 12
1   Sparkle                             0x0012c9d7 -[PhotoAssetView didSelectButton:] (PhotoAssetView.m:44)
2   UIKit                               0x3193ada3 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 91
3   UIKit                               0x3193ad3f -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 39
4   UIKit                               0x3193ad13 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 47
5   UIKit                               0x31926743 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 375
6   UIKit                               0x3193a75b -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 595
7   UIKit                               0x318fe1a1 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 5529
8   UIKit                               0x319359fd -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 773
9   UIKit                               0x319353ab -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 667
10  UIKit                               0x3190ad79 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 197
11  UIKit                               0x31909569 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 7117
12  CoreFoundation                      0x2f14cf1f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
13  CoreFoundation                      0x2f14c3e7 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 207
14  CoreFoundation                      0x2f14abd7 __CFRunLoopRun + 631
15  CoreFoundation                      0x2f0b5471 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 525
16  CoreFoundation                      0x2f0b5253 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 107
17  GraphicsServices                    0x33def2eb GSEventRunModal + 139
18  UIKit                               0x3196a845 UIApplicationMain + 1137
19  Sparkle                             0x0040a427 main (main.m:18)
```

Inside this method `[PhotoAssetView didSelectButton:]` we have calling one method using the `unsafe_unretained delegate`,

```
[self.delegate didSelectButtonForPhotoAsset:sender];
```

Any pointers?

Comment: declared as weak type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference to delegate object must be of weak type: **unsafe_unretained** or **_weak**.

If PhotoAssetView delegate (probably it is a ViewController) is **unsafe_unretained** then when referenced object is deallocated, reference is no longer valid. At this address can be other object or garbage and sending message to the address leads to exception.

To fix:

1. Use **_weak** references instead of **unsafe_unretained**. If
   reference is declared as **_weak** it is automatically set to nil
   when object deallocated (so be ready that it may became nil at
   random moment).
2. If you for some reason you still want use **unsafe_unretained** reference you must manually set the reference to nil in dealloc of your PhotoAssetView delegate object:

//SomeViewController.m

```
- (void) dealloc{
  self.photoAssetView.delegate = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you have a strong reference to the delegate elsewhere? Typically setting the delegate of an object doesn’t create a strong reference, so if you don’t keep one yourself it’s going to be freed before it ever gets called, and you’ll crash like this.

Comment: We don't have strong reference for this delegate. we can't reproduce this crash. Got the crash log from customer.